# C# SeviceSecurityContext.Current is not preseved QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, threadpool, security-context

When delegating a thread using ThreadPool.QueueuserWorkItem the ServiceSecurityContext.Current does not persist (returns null).  Several of the methods I am calling require that the security context be valid prior to returning information.

Is there a way to create a thread that will run with the same security context?  Is it possible to allow the current security context to persist or does a thread specific security context need to be setup?